# Login to devise rails app from java application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, apache, devise

I have a rails app that can sign in and sign out users and this feature is implemented using devise and i also have a java desktop application which i want to use to sign in and retrieve information from the rails app database. The model i have in rails is called webs. The `rake routes` gives the following output:

```
new_web_session GET    /webs/sign_in(.:format)          webs/sessions#new
web_session POST   /webs/sign_in(.:format)          webs/sessions#create
```

So, far i have found apache httpcomponents to be used in the java application. I have tried this:

```
public class Connectweb {

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here

     Connectweb connect = new Connectweb();

    System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
    connect.sendPost();
}
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://localhost:3000/webs/sign_in";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // add header
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("utf8", Character.toString('\u2713')));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("web[email]", "email@email.com"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("web[password]", "password"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commit", "Sign in"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
}
```

This returns the web page in `/webs/sign_in` as output:

```
    Sending 'POST' request to URL :http://example.com/webs/sign_in
    Post parameters : org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity@3173175
    Response Code : 200
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="Sign In in XOMR" name="description" />
    <meta content="log in, access account" name="keywords" />
    <title>XOMR | Sign in</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/exam_results.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/exams.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/members.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/orgs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/qr_codes.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
     <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead/bootstrap-typeahead.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/exam_results.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/exams.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/members.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/orgs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/qr_codes.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/web_registrations.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="o2QDfH4tjiOkLAXIIIzX5Nxni2ZtQUj/6ws6sKnwt6I=" name="csrf-token" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar">
    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/" class="brand">XOMR</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>

        </ul>
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/webs/sign_in" class="pull-right navbar-form" id="new_web" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="o2QDfH4tjiOkLAXIIIzX5Nxni2ZtQUj/6ws6sKnwt6I=" /></div>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="span2" id="web_email" name="web[email]" placeholder="Email" required="required" size="30" type="email" value="sushilthe@gmail.com" /></td>
                <td><input class="span2" id="web_password" name="web[password]" placeholder="Password" required="required" size="30" type="password" /></td>
                <td><input class="btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox">
                      <input name="web[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="web_remember_me" name="web[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> <label for="web_remember_me">Remember me</label>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td><small> <a href="/webs/password/new">Forgot your password?</a></small></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
</form>      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<header class="jumbotron subhead" id="overview">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <p class="lead"> Log in to access your information. </p>

  </div>
</header>
<div class = "container">
  <section id = "forms">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/webs/sign_in" class="form-horizontal, left" id="new_web" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="o2QDfH4tjiOkLAXIIIzX5Nxni2ZtQUj/6ws6sKnwt6I=" /></div>
            <div class = "row-fluid">
                <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <input class="span6" id="web_email" name="web[email]" placeholder="Email" required="required" size="30" type="email" value="sushilthe@gmail.com" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <input class="span6" id="web_password" name="web[password]" placeholder="Password" required="required" size="30" type="password" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox">
                            <input name="web[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="web_remember_me" name="web[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> <label for="web_remember_me">Remember me</label>
                    </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>    <div class="btn-group">

  <a href="/user/signup" class="btn">Sign up</a>

  <a href="/webs/password/new" class="btn">Forgot your password?</a>

  <a href="/webs/confirmation/new" class="btn">Didn&#x27;t receive confirmation instructions?</a><br />


</div>
<br>
  </section>
</div>
  <div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Home</a> / <span class="active">Sign In</span></div>
    <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <address>
        <strong>The XOMR Project</strong><br>
        P. O. Box 99999<br>
        Kathmandu, Nepal<br>
        Email: <a href="mailto:xomr.project@gmail.com">xomr.project@gmail.com</a>
      </address>
</div>
</footer>
  <pre class='debug_dump'>--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ! &#x27;?&#x27;
web: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
&nbsp; email: sushilthe@gmail.com
&nbsp; password: quartz
commit: submit
action: create
controller: webs/sessions
</pre> 
</body>
</html>
```

Please Help.

Comment: is it only ActionController error can you please show the full errors

Comment: @RajarshiDas: I have updated my question. Please Help.